# POSTMAN how to set variable within a XML request Body

Tags: xml, postman

Could you please help me with the solution, cause my {{myvariable}} doesn't work between an opened and closed tags: I send the following parameter in the POST request, application/xml content type, raw:

```
<software_id>{{SoftId}}</software_id>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as for _doesn't work_ means?

Comment: Yeah, I've got an internal error. Actually, I tried to add the pre-request script where I get the env variable I'd set earlier and it somehow worked :)